# Angular 2: How to return objects belonging to multiple classes extending superclass in one array?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, nativescript, injectable

I am trying to create a service in Angular 2-Native Script app that defines an array of news items, and has several methods that operates on the same data. These news items can be of different types, e.g. Big , small, etc each  of which may have different parameters .

I have defined the interface and the service as below.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

export interface NewsItem {
type: "big" | "small" |"referral";
title: string;
text: string;
imageUrl?: string;
}

export interface Referral extends NewsItem {
type: "referral";
username: string;
}


@Injectable()
export class NewsService {
    private data = [ 
        { type: "big", title: "This is one big item!", text: "Lorem ipsum     dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus iaculis, turpis vitae ornare accumsan, arcu tortor ultrices nunc, eu aliquam libero sapien vitae tellus.", imageUrl: "https://octodex.github.com/images/octocat-de-los-muertos.jpg" }, 
        { type: "small", title: "Yes, we code!", text: "Vivamus a sem eget erat feugiat hendrerit at quis massa. Nullam varius ac eros non dignissim. Fusce gravida arcu libero.", imageUrl: "https://octodex.github.com/images/baracktocat.jpg" },
        { type: "referral", title: "Yes, we code!", username:"Vasanthi Subramaniam", text: "Vivamus a sem eget erat feugiat hendrerit at quis massa. Nullam varius ac eros non dignissim. Fusce gravida arcu libero.", imageUrl: "https://octodex.github.com/images/baracktocat.jpg" }
    ]   

private getItems(): NewsItem {
        let result:NewsItem[] = this.data;

    return result;
}
}
```

I am getting an error as follows:

```
Type '({ type: string; title: string; text: string; imageUrl: string; } 
| { type: string; title: string...' is not assignable to type 'NewsItem[]'
```

How can I define the array such that it is assignable to News Items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cast your object explicitly to the Referral class:

```
private data = [ 
    { type: "big", title: "This is one big item!", text: "Lorem ipsum     dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus iaculis, turpis vitae ornare accumsan, arcu tortor ultrices nunc, eu aliquam libero sapien vitae tellus.", imageUrl: "https://octodex.github.com/images/octocat-de-los-muertos.jpg" }, 
    { type: "small", title: "Yes, we code!", text: "Vivamus a sem eget erat feugiat hendrerit at quis massa. Nullam varius ac eros non dignissim. Fusce gravida arcu libero.", imageUrl: "https://octodex.github.com/images/baracktocat.jpg" },
    <Referral>{ type: "referral", title: "Yes, we code!", username:"Vasanthi Subramaniam", text: "Vivamus a sem eget erat feugiat hendrerit at quis massa. Nullam varius ac eros non dignissim. Fusce gravida arcu libero.", imageUrl: "https://octodex.github.com/images/baracktocat.jpg" }
]
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried casting the object to the referral class as suggested. Still getting errors as follows
Type '(Referral | { type: string; title: string; text: string; imageUrl: string; })[]' is not assignable to type 'NewsItem[]'.
    Type '{ type: string; title: string; text: string; imageUrl: string; }' is not assignable to type 'NewsItem'.
      Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"big" | "small" | "referral" | "interestLink"'.

Comment: Thaknks Alexander. Your suggestion worked. The error in my earlier comment was because I did not type getItems() correctly!